# Cannot refresh unmanaged object - but it is managed (?)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a mysql table with a date column that sets a timestamp by default; I insert a new row with the following function, and it works (I see the data in the database, including the timestamp), but it doesn't show up in a subsequent query, so I am trying to get `em.refresh()` to refresh the cache, but it fails with an exception:

```
public String createItems(Items item){
    String msg="";

    logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 1 id:"+item.getId());
    try{
        if (item.getId()!=null){
            logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 2");
            em.merge(item);
            logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 3");
            Items itm=em.find(item.getClass(), item.getId());
            logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 3a "+itm.getId()+", "+itm.getName()+", "+itm.getCreated());
        }
        else{
            logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 4");
            em.persist(item);
            logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 5");
        }
        em.refresh(item);
        logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 6");
        em.flush();
        logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 7");
    }
    catch (PersistenceException e){
        msg=e.getMessage();
        logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 8 msg: "+msg);           
    }
    logger.info("OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 9");
    return msg;
}
```

By following the log output, I can see that it is the call to `em.refresh()`:

```
[2017-11-01T12:27:05.994+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [docdb.ItemsSession] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539225994] [levelValue: 800] [[
  OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 1 id:3]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:05.994+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [docdb.ItemsSession] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539225994] [levelValue: 800] [[
  OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 2]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:05.995+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/root/projects/office/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_officePU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539225995] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT id, changed, created, descr, doc, name, doctype, item_id FROM office_db.documents WHERE (item_id = ?)
        bind => [3]]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:05.997+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/root/projects/office/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_officePU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539225997] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT svalue, attribute_id, item_id, ivalue FROM item_attributes WHERE (item_id = ?)
        bind => [3]]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:05.998+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [docdb.ItemsSession] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539225998] [levelValue: 800] [[
  OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 3]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:05.998+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [docdb.ItemsSession] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539225998] [levelValue: 800] [[
  OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 6]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:06.005+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/root/projects/office/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_officePU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539226005] [levelValue: 500] [[
  UPDATE office_db.items SET created = ?, name = ? WHERE (id = ?)
        bind => [null, Case 3, 3]]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:06.246+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [docdb.ItemsSession] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539226246] [levelValue: 800] [[
  OFFICE ItemsSession.createItems 7 3, Case 3, null]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:06.559+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [AS-EJB-00056] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539226559] [levelValue: 900] [[
  A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ItemsSession, method: public java.lang.String docdb.ItemsSession.createItems(docdb.Items)]]

[2017-11-01T12:27:06.559+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1509539226559] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot refresh unmanaged object: docdb.Items[ id=3 ].
...
```

But why? As far as I can see, `item` is clearly managed, and I have checked that the ID hasn't changed, or am I missing something?

Comment: `em.contains(myObj)` returns what? since we don't see any transaction demarcation ...

Comment: False, as it turns out. I tried briefly to set a transaction manually, but of course, I can't when I use JTA.

Comment: What is returned by `em.merge` presumably is "managed" (i.e em.contains == true), ditto for `em.find` object.

Comment: You are right - I can refresh the `Item` returned by `em.merge`. However, it doesn't give me what I had hoped: that the date value would show up in the subsequent query (in essence a `select * from items`). I'll have to do some more work. But you have been a great help - thx.

Comment: I cat get the missing date column to show up in the list by looping through it and calling `em.refresh` on each - is that really the best way?

Comment: Do you understand that by calling refresh on the item you just merged you are wiping out any changes made?  What exactly is the problem you are looking to solve, as you have not pointed it out or how it is occurring. If I were to guess, your problem is that you are querying for all items outside of the transaction where you are adding it and the transaction hasn't committed yet.  Flushing only puts the statements in the database, but they are not visible to other sessions until it commits.

Comment: Chris - briefly: My table, ITEMS, has a date column that gets set by default to current time by MySQL. I insert a row without specifying that column. I then load a list of ITEMS to display on a JSF page - however, the `List<Items>` returned from the query doesn't have the value for the date column set. A solution is to run through the list and call `em.refresh` on each `Items` in the list - it works for me, although no doubt I will refine it later to not always load the whole table. My remaining question is just: Is there a better way - like could I set an option?

Comment: Refresh on each requires a database query to reload. I'd suggest setting it through the application, possibly using a prePersist event method, or you can look into EclipseLink's ReturnInsert functionality https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/index.html?org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/ReturnInsert.html though it requires database support.  Or instead of calling em.refresh on each individual Item, you can add the refresh query hint to the query obtaining your list https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints#Refresh

Comment: @Chris this is really useful - I can see that I would benefit from both the FLUSH and REFRESH hints. However, I can't seem to find the correct reference; the examples talk about importing org.eclipse.persistence.config.HintValues and org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints, which I don't seem to have (working from NetBeans 8.2) - also, all my other persistence imports come from javax.persistence.* - do you know where I can find the right reference (my persistence.xml says I use EclipseLink JPA 2.1)?

Comment: javax.persistence are JPA classes, while the hints are EclipseLink specific. You will need to add the EclipseLink jars to the compile classpath.